# css properties not working properly in class.col function

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to apply certain css properties in particular area i.e."Dashboard" and I have assigned a class name "main" for div.col function under html for the same but when I try to apply css property in it, it gets applied to whole page.

here's the code for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
<body>
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
<!--navbar starts here  -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Dashboard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> Settings</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a></li>


    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Add Users</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far fa-copy"></i> Add Categories</a></li>


    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--navbar ends </here>-->

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
 <ul class="nav flex-column sidebar">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Reports</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Stats</a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Graphs</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Users</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav flex-column sidebar">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Reports</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Revenues</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Countries</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Spammers</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
           <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">

           <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1></div>

    </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
[![body{
        font-family: 'Rosario' ;

}

.sidebar{
    margin:10px -8px 20px 20px; 
}

.sidebar>li>a{
    padding:  20px 20px;
}

.main{
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-color: lightgray;

}]
```

**I want my page to look exactly like this.**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/odqIK.png

**Right now it is looking like this:**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgL6l.png

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how you'll want to proceed with this project.
For what you asked, I'd go about:
no need to wrap your h1:

```
<h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1></div>
```

around a div.

Then, you can add your classes to your h1 and add a max-height to its css and adjust positioning with padding.
HTML:

```
    <!--navbar ends </here>-->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
            <ul class="nav flex-column sidebar">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Stats</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Graphs</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Users</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav flex-column sidebar">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Revenues</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Countries</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Spammers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 class="page-header col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Rosario';

}

.sidebar {
    margin: 10px -8px 20px 20px;
}

.sidebar>li>a {
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

.main {
    padding-top: 30px;
    max-height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgray;

}
```